# How to change dynamically GET request in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, loops, foreach, azure-logic-apps

I've only started playing with Azure Logic Apps and already bumped into some problem.

The app that I'm trying to develop has a fairly simple logic: call the API, get the data and then save it to the Blob storage.

[App Logic app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cHwH.png)

It works perfectly fine for a single request (`https://example.com/rest/businessObject/objectName/details?fields=abc,dde`). However, I would like to make multiple get requests to various objects getting different fields, i.e. change the *objectName* in the URI and *fields* values in the get request. Is it possible to parametrize the call using something like JSON object, iterate over it and make different requests in a single app instead of creating multiple apps for each request? And if it's possible then how?

**Update**

I've used JSON parsing (big thanks to the author of [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324036/how-to-loop-through-an-array-in-a-logic-app)  in this thread). Now my app looks like this:

[image]

Seems to work fine:

[image]

The problem that I have now however is different - I can't save the body of the response as blob as I can't access it in the create blob. The only variable available for Blob content is 'Current item' which, of course, is a chunk of JSON used in the for loop. Any ideas if it's possible to save it to the storage and how to get it done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do JSON parsing itself, use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) example.

You can also do [nesting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint), and also use [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values) and call different Logic App from another and that can be [nested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint) or [loops or if-else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement).

If you have a fixed number of requests and not infinite then make those Logic apps, and using variables make use of Nested Logic App calls. If you have an in-definite (un-fixed) amount of API calls then a better idea would be to use [Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) or even may be Azure Logic App as an [orchestrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-examples-and-scenarios) which then uses Azure Functions in nested calls.